# How to make gdb emit the commands it is executing in batch mode

Tags: gdb, batch-processing

Is there a way to call `gdb --batch --commands some_gdb_script some_executable` and have it emit *both* the commands it executes, along with the command results?  I do not want to install anything other than gdb, such as xdotool etc. It should just work within stock gdb with no extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have it emit both the commands it executes, along with the command results?

See [this](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8822) bug.

Using `set trace-commands on` *almost* achieves the desired result.

Comment: I would have never figured that out on my own. Thank you!